# Webservice - Multiple file output formats

Tags: json, web-services, http, audio

I need to create one webservice, that is used to download an audio(wav) file from server by taking input one string id. If audio file is not present at server, i need to send error back in json format.

Now the questions is - How to give the extension for downloaded file. I have no prior idea whether response will be success or failure.

What i am doing now is after dowloading a file - i am changing extension of file using Contet-Type header in response according to audio/wav or application/json.

Is there any way to specify file name with extension from server only. i.e downloaded file with name and extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could set:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME
```

header on the server side setting a proper xyz.json or xyz.wav filename as described in [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183).